# Jmeter~ Performanc testing

Tags: jmeter, xmlhttprequest, performance-testing

I’ve prepared my jmeter script of some http request using browser dev tools, while running the test jmeter sending different request instead of browser dev tools request, Can anyone help me with this?

Can someone help me with issue in which my jmeter saying 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

Try recording your test using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), this way you will get the confidence that URLs are correct as [HTTP Status 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) means that the resource cannot be found under the given URL so most probably you made a typo.

Also pay attention to [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and other [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) as it might be the case you're not providing valid authentication context and it causes HTTP 404 errors and make sure to [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) any dynamic parameters.